# JQuery Form validation not working in IE or FF

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My form validation does not work (in IE or FF -- so i guess it is broke full stop)
I am using JQuery 1.7.2

Can u see what is wrong..?

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validateutils.js"></script>


<form action="mailto:p.morrison@domain.com?subject=Changes to Employment"   id="employmentForm" method="post" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="location.href='thank_you_changes_to_employment.html';">
```

My mandatory input fields have a class of {validate:{required:true}}

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function ()
{
        $('#employmentForm').validate ();
});
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made two small changes and your code is working fine.

1)  Quote OP:  *"My mandatory input fields have a `class` of `{validate:{required:true}}`"*.  Simply use `class="required"` within your HTML markup of the mandatory input elements.

2)  Remove the inline `onsubmit` handler because it will interfere with the plugin. Instead, use the `submitHandler` callback function of the plugin.  This `submitHandler` will *only* fire when the form is valid.

```
$(function () {

    $('#employmentForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
           form.submit();  // <-- default form action
           location.href='thank_you_changes_to_employment.html';
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/8Y8Tt/**

If this doesn't solve it, you'll need to show more code including your HTML markup.

Answer (score -1):

try to bind/load your script after the page has fully loaded. I think the script is triggered even if the element(form) do not exist yet.
usually, it is TOP-BOTTOM process, so you can either do this:

> ```
>      $(document).ready( function() {
>          $('#employmentForm').validate();
>      } );
> ```

or simply put your script after the form end tag

> ```
>      <form id="employmentForm">
>      <!-- Your form elements -->
>      </form>
>      <script>
>          $(function () {
>              $('#employmentForm').validate ();
>          });
>      </script>
> ```

Comment: FYI:  `$(function (){` is the same exact thing as `$(document).ready(function(){`  See:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/